# Grails ApplicationCommand hibernate session issue

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I use grails 3.0.17 and h2db on my project.

I created ApplicationCommand to populate some test data. I run it like 'grails gradle generateTestData'.

```
class GenerateTestData implements ApplicationCommand {

    @Override
    boolean handle(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        //Host is domain object
        Host.withNewSession { session ->
           //some domain opertions
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

I run generateTestData command when db is not created yet. Bootstrap.groovy script create database and populate bootstrap data. Then my script perform few save() calls. I see via Squirrel that data is correct in DB. But when i run my app with 'grails run-app' it throws 'UserNotFound' exception (but user is in the DB, check via Squirrel).

So it seems like something wrong with session or DB connection.

When i run grails run-app (db is not created yet), Bootstrap.groovy script create DB and populate data. And everything working fine.

I can't understand what's wrong with command. Can anyone helps me? (App can't find user even if command with empty handle() function was run).